# Is there a UNIX-like clustered OS that can work across internet connections?

Tags: shell, unix, ssh, cluster-computing

Is there already is some sort of clustered system, like some basic kernel+shell that can work across different computers, one I can log in and be in some sort of shared filesystem+resources ?

For example I often am using SSH but also want direct file access to the computer I'm SSH-ing, so what I usually do is using also FTP (since I'm not a vi or emacs user, but that's another matter).

I also thought "what if I login into some special kind of cluster in which I can use the 'write' command".

UNIX is old now, are there systems that already work like that instead of being server-centered, and can they work with internet connections ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this was the point of [Plan 9 from Bell Labs](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/plan9/). It's old now but you should check out its derivatives like Inferno, Amoeba, [OpenSSI](http://openssi.org) and Kerrighed.

Comment: Well I should have thought my question better, my goal was rather some end-user software rather than a kernel.